# A vertical overflow on a band with horizontal print order

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report with this design:

[image]

There are columns called ***Składniki odżywcze*** (means: nutrients) in this report. Those columns are made using a data source and *horizontal print order*.

A content of each column is made using a *subreport* with this design:

[image: Subreport design in iReport]

This subreport grows vertically and when I have a lot of nutrients and they don't fit into a page I get ***`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Subreport overflowed on a band that does not support overflow.`***. I read it's caused because I have *horizontal print order* and my content grows vertically too much.

What can I do now? I'd like the page was breaked and the rest of nutrients were displayed on the next page.

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Comment: Yes and no. I set smaller font and I believe it's enough. Till today a client hasn't issued a bug regarding this ;)